# How to use Conditional Union ALL in table-valued function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Following is inline table valued function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDipForDirectClientCharts]
(
  @FacilityId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ,
  @PatientChartStatusCompleteEnum SMALLINT ,
  @PatientChartLockingInterval SMALLINT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(            
    WITH    DirectPatientChartCTE
              --Get all patient charts that qualify for dip criteria   
              AS ( SELECT TOP 500
                            VisitNumber,PatientChartID
                   FROM     PatientChartCorporate WITH ( READPAST )
                   WHERE    PatientChartCorporate.IsDeleted = 0
                            AND PatientChartCorporate.IsErroneous = 0
                            AND PatientChartCorporate.FacilityId = @FacilityId
                            AND ( DipFileName IS NULL
                                  OR DipFileName = ''
                                )
                            AND PatientChartCorporate.ChartStatusID = @PatientChartStatusCompleteEnum
                            AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CompletedOn, GETUTCDATE()) >= +CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @PatientChartLockingInterval)
                            AND ( PatientChartCorporate.CompletedOn IS NOT NULL )
                 ),
            RemotePatientChartCTE
              AS ( SELECT TOP 500
                            VisitNumber,PatientChartID
                   FROM     PatientCharts WITH ( READPAST )
                   WHERE    PatientCharts.IsDeleted = 0
                            AND PatientCharts.IsErroneous = 0
                            AND PatientCharts.FacilityId = @FacilityId
                            AND ( DipFileName IS NULL
                                  OR DipFileName = ''
                                )
                            AND PatientCharts.ChartStatusID = @PatientChartStatusCompleteEnum
                            AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CompletedOn, GETUTCDATE()) >= +CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @PatientChartLockingInterval)
                            AND ( PatientCharts.CompletedOn IS NOT NULL )
                 )
SELECT  PatientCharts.VisitNumber ,
        PatientChartImages.ImageSequence AS ImageSequence
FROM    dbo.PatientChartImagesCorporate AS PatientChartImages WITH ( READPAST )
        INNER JOIN DirectPatientChartCTE AS PatientCharts ON PatientChartImages.PatientChartId = PatientCharts.PatientChartId
WHERE   Patientchartimages.OnbasedDate IS NULL
UNION ALL
( SELECT    PatientCharts.VisitNumber ,
            PatientChartImages.ImageSequence AS ImageSequence
  FROM      dbo.PatientChartImages AS PatientChartImages WITH ( READPAST )
            INNER JOIN RemotePatientChartCTE AS PatientCharts ON PatientChartImages.PatientChartId = PatientCharts.PatientChartId
  WHERE     Patientchartimages.OnbasedDate IS NULL
)
   )
```

I have defined two CTE, `DirectPatientChartCTE` and `RemotePatientChartCTE`. I don't want to use union all in case 0 records are returned by `RemotePatientChartCTE`.

I understand that I can use a where clause in query below union all to check for 0 records in CTE. In that case also second query will be evaluated. I don't want tables in second query to be scanned in case records don't exist.

This has been changed from a view to inline TVF since performance with a view was horrible. I cannot use a SP since I have to fill a dynamic temporary table with the results of this TVF. Please suggest.

Comment: When one of the tables in the query is going to return 0 rows, and it's `INNER JOIN`ed to other tables in the query, then no *actual* scans of the other tables should occur, assuming the optimizer can do its job well and the indexes are appropriate. Producing 0 results is usually a fast operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn your function into a multi statement table valued function. Execute the queries in your CTE's one at a time and store the result from each query in a table variable each. Then you can check for row count in your second table variable and do the union query if necessary.

In pseudo code something like this.

```
declare @Direct table
(
  PatientChartID int primary key,
  VisitNumber int
)

declare @Remote table
(
  PatientChartID int primary key,
  VisitNumber int
)

insert into @Direct 
select top 500 VisitNumber,PatientChartID
from PatientChartCorporate
--where ....

insert into @Remote
select top 500 VisitNumber,PatientChartID
from PatientChartCorporate
--where ....

if exists(select * from @Remote)
begin
  -- union query here

end
else
begin
  -- non union query here

end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this valuable suggestion. I am of the opinion that multi statement table valued function has a performance penalty associated with it related to TEMPDB. since this query will be fired every 5 minutes, it can cause a lot of contention. Please suggest.

Comment: Please try and see. I think the over all performance of your query could be better if you split it up in parts. If appropriate, you can also define a primary key on your table variables () to speed up the joins when you query the table variable. I'm a bit confused about the columns returned from your CTE's. You return `VisitNumber` and use `PatientChartId` in the join. Also you have a `top ` with no `order by`.

Comment: The difference in behavior between an inline TVF and a multi statement TVF is that the inline is expanded into the query that uses the function making it possible for the query optimizer to figure out a different plan. Basically it replaces the call to the function in the calling query with the statement in the inline function and then starts creating the queryplan. A multi statement TVF must be executed as is first and then the result is incorporated to the outer query.